# I cannot boot from a Ubuntu CD / DVD

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I am trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10. After burning the ISO and then booting the disc, I get to the purple menu that asks whether I want to Try, install, or check disk. Any option I select yields a black screen with a random letter highlighted in a random color. I have tried the UEFI boot as well, and I get a GRUB menu asking the same options, and yielding the same results. I have tried nomodeset, and that hasn't seemed to work. Anyone got any ideas?

System Specs:

- ASUS P8Z77-V
- WD 500gb HDD
- 2x WD 128gb HDD (1 for backup, 1 for media storage)
- Nvidia Quadro 295 NVS
- i5-3570k
- 8gb Corsair Vengeance RAM

Comment: I had a computer that couldn't boot Ubuntu from any installation media, neither DVD nor USB. Finally I got it to boot Ubuntu 13.10 from a USB flash drive using the Ubuntu Mini CD. The step-by-step is procedure is explained in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384590/install-ubuntu-along-with-windows-8-1-blackscreen/384598#384598). I also have additional information about how to install the Ubuntu desktop from the Ubuntu Mini CD which I haven't posted yet. If you want to try it, comment with any questions you might have and I  will try to answer them.

Comment: @karel - I tried the Mini install of Ubuntu 13.10 x64 and it seemed to be working fine, until it got to the detecting hardware section. The computer became unresponsive on that screen, keyboard frozen, blue light on computer frozen as well. Did this happen to you?

Comment: No, my Ubuntu Mini CD didn't have any problem detecting hardware. That you got a "detecting hardware" message at all may be indicative a problem detecting a peripheral device (the Nvidia Quadro 295 NVS graphics card???) rather than the processor or motherboard. Frozen keyboard and mouse frequently means nothing related to graphics is responding as well.

Comment: @karel - So I am up the creek without a paddle... is there anything I could do?? All of my peripheral devices work as they should in Windows 7, I don't know why they wouldn't work for Ubuntu.

Comment: USB boot sometimes has problems with specific models of graphics cards. I have seen it happen that if you temporarily swap the graphics card with another graphics card, the Ubuntu live USB will boot. The reason why it works with Windows and not Ubuntu may be that you have the Windows driver installation disk for your Nvidia Quadro 295 NVS graphics card.

Comment: @karel - Ah that makes more sense. I have another Nvidia Quadro 295 NVS I could switch it with... but that wouldn't help. Could I try using the integrated graphics on my i5?

Comment: It might work. And if you can get Ubuntu installed, then you can put the graphics card back in and then search the Dash to find the _Additional Drivers_ icon and then open Additional Drivers and install the driver for your graphics card.

Comment: @karel - I tried with just onboard graphics, and it stalled at the same location on the install. I am going to try unplugging the Optical Drive and mouse and see if that gets me anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to my problem; I disconnected the Optical Drive, and the Live USB booted without a hiccup. Don't know why it was causing a problem, but I plugged it in and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use  `Unetbootin`. It is a USB boot software.It is similar to standard installation,so is more reliable.

It is available is Ubuntu software center. You can boot ISO file or download one from Internet using Unetbootin.
[image]

As shown in this image.you have to select the iso(or the distribution) and select the correct Usb drive.then click ok.

> Note that only fat32 partition is supported.

Comment: I tried this program, and now I cannot even get to a Ubuntu menu. It boots the flash drive straight to a blank screen, and then everything freezes after a minute or so.