# Dual-boot Windows/Ubuntu error, can't install

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, system-installation, usb

I'm beginner with Linux, and I want to make Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1, so I've process like on [this video](//www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uVcsFhv2Vo).

But when I restart my computer (with <kbd>F12</kbd>) on USB storage and that I want install Ubuntu their are their 2 line:

```
[     6.592492] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Coaching mode page found
[     6.592493] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write throught
```

and next nothing... the installation didn't work

I've detail my problem with pics here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1c9k0d46juddyr_B6chFnzA_tIIAEbUD2uWFnAY0IrrE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a bootable USB stick?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/191980/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick)

Comment: Not a duplicate in my opnion, as it is a detailed in a particular error.

Answer (score 1):

1. See [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported). There are some BIOS settings that have been known to interfere with booting from a USB drive on computers the came with Windows 8 preinstalled. They are: Secure Boot, Quick Boot/Fast Boot, Intel Smart Response Technology (SRT) and Fast Startup.
2. UNetbootin does not support Windows 8. That is why you got the following error message:

   ```
   [     6.592492] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
   [     6.592493] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through  
   _
   ```

   Update: UNetbootin has been updated and currently supports both Windows 8 and Windows 10.

   At the official Ubuntu webpage: [How to create a bootable USB
   stick on Windows](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) you will find step-by-step illustrated instructions for creating a bootable USB stick on Windows including Windows 8. The recommended program in this tutorial is [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) which supports Windows 8 and Windows 10, and that is why Rufus is recommended by the official Ubuntu website to create a bootable USB
   stick on Windows, even though the UNetbootin program is an Ubuntu program that is in the Ubuntu Software Center.

   The minimal requirements for making a bootable USB stick with Rufus are a USB stick that has at least 2GB available space, and for Ubuntu 18.04 and later a USB stick that has at least 4GB available space.

Comment: I have the same problem with pendrivelinux .... :/

Comment: 1. See [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) 2. UNetbootin doesn't work, Universal USB Installer doesn't work and even Rufus which sometimes works when the other two don't work doesn't work on your computer. It's time to go hardcore and try the Ubuntu installer that always works because it's text only -- the Ubuntu minimal CD: http://askubuntu.com/questions/384590/installing-ubuntu-ends-in-a-black-screen-in-msi-ge60/384598#384598

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand French, but Unetbootin appears to be failing. Am I right? I'd recommend using Rufus to burn the ISO to a flash drive. It's worked perfectly for me.

Comment: And I have the same error with Rufus...

Comment: @RémiBoulardot hmm. Try re-downloading the ISO.

Comment: Yes I've try... :/

Answer (score 0):

I would try the option. "Try Ubuntu without installing" them inside that you can see if it works and install Ubuntu in a cleaner interface.

Or I would try Pen drive Linux
http://www.pendrivelinux.com

Though I usually recommend unetbootin.

Comment: I have the same problem with pendrivelinux :/

Comment: Try make another bootable USB on another computer, maybe, for some reason there is a fault with your particular PC's way to make it?