# mini.iso doesn't appear in Startup Disk Creator

Tags: usb-creator

I am interested to make a clean install of Lubuntu Core with the mini.iso from a USB Stick. I am not interested to create a Live USB.

I've done my best to add from "Other" button form the Startup Disk Creator the mini.iso but doesn't appear anything like in here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/In...n/FromUSBStick

I've tried also..

```
sudo chmod a+r "location"/mini.iso
usb-creator-gtk -i "location"/mini.iso
```

And when the Startup Disk Creator opens, the mini.iso still not appears.

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

apt-cache policy lubuntu-desktop
lubuntu-desktop:
  Installed: 0.55
  Candidate: 0.55
  Version table:
 *** 0.55 0
        500 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I don't think that the old partition is Encrypted, when I installed Lubuntu I remember that I chose not to encrypt it... if this could be important for you. But better if you know exactly how to check it to be sure.

Thank you.

Comment: It's been a while since I put the mini CD iso on a USB stick, but [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384590/installing-ubuntu-ends-in-a-black-screen-in-msi-ge60/384598#384598) is how I did it with Ubuntu 13.10. I'm also looking for some up-to-date information.

Comment: I can confirm that this same behaviour happens on my 14.04 system.  Probably best to use dd as @karel suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to this site: http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-a-minimal-ubuntu-on-old-laptop/

"You won’t be able to create a USB startup disk with this iso file, so the only way is to burn it into a bootable CD."

**BUT IT'S DATED...**

**EDIT:**

Based on quick google search, Unetbootin should work fine:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unetbootin/

Just select your mini.iso...

### I CAN CONFIRM, IT DOES WORK! (15.04)

Comment: Excuse me @Michal Hagara  I am interested to make a clean install of Lubuntu Core with the mini.iso, not a Live USB Stick, is it possible to do it with Unetbootin please?

Comment: I have installed OS from USB stick created with Unetbootin many times, it boots as Live CD with option to install the OS. After pluging my mini.iso USB into USB port, Unetbootin menu appeared, I pressed Enter...Language selection appeared ...As would probably do with OS burned on CD.

Comment: Just to add, I can confirm this works with 14.04 x64 mini.iso

Answer (score 0):

I would like to be clear that with the mini.iso I am interested to make a clean install of Lubuntu Core...

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  18.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 102.5G  0 part /home
├─sda4   8:4    0 108.1G  0 part /windows
└─sda5   8:5    0   3.7G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7.2G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   7.2G  0 part /media/multix/0AA3-23B8
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I've tried the dd method but still nothing happened...

I've tried like that:

```
    cd ~/Downloads/
    md5sum 'mini.iso'
a2502844750ecb6477d8fb4ff6b9aaf8  mini.iso
```

md5sum is ok.

```
    cd ~/Downloads/  
    sudo su  
    dd if='mini.iso' of=/dev/sdb bs=4096
7936+0 records in
7936+0 records out
32505856 bytes (33 MB) copied, 2.33314 s, 13.9 MB/s
```

When I access the USB Stick I can't see any files on it, but when I go to Startup Disk Creator the "Label" of the stick is "Firmware" now and the capacity of it is 6.0 MB and the free space from it is 6.0 MB too...

THis is how it looks after I use dd

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  18.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 102.5G  0 part /home
├─sda4   8:4    0 108.1G  0 part /windows
└─sda5   8:5    0   3.7G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   7.2G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1    25M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   1     6M  0 part /media/multix/Firmware
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
loop1    7:1    0    31M  1 loop /media/iso
```

It could be possible that the USB stick to be mounted?
Can someone say it from this?

```
sudo mkdir /media/iso/
sudo mount -o loop /home/multix/Downloads/mini.iso /media/isomount: block device /home/multix/Downloads/mini.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
```